# PowerShell: Getting Help on Get-Process -Property CPU

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

With PowerShell 3, I tried to get help on what properties are available for CPU; while using Get-Process. I just tried a shot in the dark, as below:

```
Help Get-Process -Property CPU
```

But, failed. Any help, please!

Answer (score 4):

What are you looking for? Information about your processor? `Get-Process` list running processes(e.g. internet explorer) on your computer, not info about your processor-chips(CPU). Ex:

```
Get-Process
```

Output:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName                                                                        
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------                                                                        
    284      25     7128       8748   103            1608 AppleMobileDeviceService                                                           
     75       7     1136       1528    44            1588 armsvc                                                                             
    703      82     6612       7732   114     1,25   4212 AsusAudioCenter
```

Information about your processor can be found using:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor
```

Output:

```
Caption           : Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7
DeviceID          : CPU0
Manufacturer      : GenuineIntel
MaxClockSpeed     : 3400
Name              : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz
SocketDesignation : LGA1155
```

To get all properties about your CPU use `Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | fl *`. To get a list of avaiable properties, use the `Get-Member` cmdlet to examine the object that `Get-WmiObject`returns:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Get-Member
```

Answer (score 3):

Your shot in the dark missed.  Also, since your description of what went wrong is nothing more than "But, failed.", I can only guess at what your problem might be.  In order to better help you use help you need to help us by providing pertinent information about your problem such as error messages.

Firstly, `Help` (or the [`Get-Help` cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849696.aspx)) does not have a `-Property` parameter.  `-Parameter` might be what you looking for, however running `Help Get-Process -Parameter CPU` will reveal that the [`Get-Process` cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849832.aspx) does not have a `CPU` parameter.

Secondly, `Get-Process` returns instances of the [`System.Diagnostics.Process` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx).  The documentation or running `Get-Process | Get-Member` will show you what properties that class exposes.  You can retrieve them by running something like...

```
Get-Process | Select-Object -Property (
    'ProcessName',
    'Id',
    'ProcessorAffinity',
    'UserProcessorTime',
    'PrivilegedProcessorTime',
    'TotalProcessorTime'
);
```

Finally, unlike previous versions PowerShell 3.0 does not install local help content.  You need to run the [`Update-Help` cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849720.aspx) to download and install help content.  Alternatively, when running `Get-Help` you can pass the `-Online` parameter which will open the help content from MSDN in a web browser.